# Domain hijack or spam?

Tags: domains, dns, web-hosting

I've changed my DNS from a host to a new host. It took about a day to propagate. Now my site has factious home page from a "searchdiscovered.com".

I crosschecked the DNS, it is as required by the new host.The "searchdiscovered.com" pages are not inserted by the new host either.

My question is : Is it possible to for someone to insert their homepage while the DNS propagation is in progress? What is the way out?

Answer (score 1):

There was a header problem. Solved by creating the right pointer at the host admin's control panel. BTW , the "searchdiscovered.com" seems the default catchall kind of page put by the host company! If your heads are not defined properly, they shows these pages. They try to make some business gain out of such missing by the customer!

Answer (score 0):

You have probably misconfigured the domain alias at the new host.

Web requests will arrive at the new host (assuming shared hosting server, here). It will look at the 'host header' of the HTTP request, to see what site it is actually for. It searches for the name of that domain (the one you configured in DNS) in it's configuration. If it cannot find it, you'll get the default page of your shared hosting webserver.

You'll need to make the host header match the name of your configured site at the shared hosting server.

Comment: Thank You!! So this has to be done at the hosting account or at the domain account. Sorry I'm not explaining it clearly. Should I contact the support of the host or from where I bought the domain. Both are different.

Comment: You bought the domain, but apparently have self-administered DNS; Assuming that your cross-checking was correct, this leaves the configuration of your shared host. Contacting support (i.e. find their FAQ) is certainly a good step here. _+1 for separating these services BTW. This way you can move your business if required!_